# how in SQL to sum up (+1) and down (-1) votes using 1 and 0 values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I realized this issue when trying to sum upvotes **AND** downvotes because the value of a downvote is -1 and not 0. This causes a problem when using the SQL sum() function. For example,

```
vote_id   vote
  1        0
  2        1
  3        1

SELECT sum(vote) //output is 2

vote_id   vote
  1       -1
  2        1
  3        1

SELECT sum(vote) //output is 1, which is the desired output
```

I guess first off, my question is, is using `0, null, and 1` even make sense? Or should I should I just use `-1, 0, 1`?

Regardless, i'd be interested to know what the SQL query would look like to to sum up and down votes using `0, null, and 1`.

Comment: Why would you *not* use -1, 0, 1?

Comment: hi @Juhana, i guess its because I want to keep things simple in my head but at the same time use best practices. 0 and 1 is standard for everything else, so was concerned about making an exception in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't this only be a boolean to determine whether the vote was positive or negative? As if there's no vote, then there's no record. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why not just set the default vote to -1?

Comment: The 0 and 1 is standard for anything that's yes/no, or on/off. A positive/negative vote is not a yes/no choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally would use `-1`, `0` and `1`.

However, `0`, `NULL` and `1` can also be made to work:

```
SELECT SUM(vote * 2 - 1) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

So the question would be: *Is `NULL` excluded when computing aggregate functions?*

And the answer is YES. [Wikipedia's article on NULL values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) states:

> SQL defines aggregate functions to simplify server-side aggregate
>   calculations on data. Almost all aggregate functions perform a
>   Null-elimination step, so that Null values are not included in the
>   final result of the calculation. This implicit Null elimination,
>   however, can have an impact on aggregate function results.

Hence it doesn't matter whether you do `0` or `NULL` for values you want excluded from the `SUM` aggregate function.

Comment: There is a difference...  Try `AVG()`.  For which reason I'd prefer `-1, NULL, 1`

Comment: @Dems You're right, I updated my answer to apply only to `SUM` aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

in oracle it would be

```
SUM( decode( vote,0,-1,vote ))
```

Comment: thanks for providing that answer for Oracle users, i'm using mysql, let me try that query real quick...

Comment: dang, unfortunately there does not appear to be a `decode()` function in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

A simple calculation changes the vote column values to -1 and +1.

```
SUM( 2*(vote-0.5))
```

Or take the difference in count between the two.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE vote = 1)
      -(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE vote = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should definitely use 1, 0, and -1. It just makes everything easier. You also may not save any space using a single bit field, so there's no real good reason to try to use that here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CASE` for something like this - I do it a lot in SQL Server, and assume it should be valid in MySQL as well:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN Vote = 0 THEN -1 ELSE VOTE END) as 'Votes'
FROM
   MyTable
```

Answer (score -1):

`select count (*) from table where vote <> 1` (for the amount of -1)

`select count (*) from table where vote = 1` (for the amount of 1)

Comment: <>1 includes nulls which I think does not give the correct answer plus an explanation would be useful